# Anti-infringment IP list

Tags: data-request, internet

I am looking for an up-to-date, gratis anti-infringment IP list, i.e., a list of IPs of organizations searching for copyright infringement through peer-to-peer networks.

https://www.iblocklist.com/lists has such a list, but the access to it is not free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that many people now think blocklists won't work well, but this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/696rsu/what_blocklists_do_you_people_use_with_torrent/) has an alternative to iblocklist

http://john.bitsurge.net/public/biglist.p2p.gz

---

And here's a bash script to get the lists from iblocklist (scroll down for comments)

https://gist.github.com/johntyree/3331662

Comment: i think blocklists are overkill and people unintentionally get blocked, which is unfortunate. the reality though is that i haven't been the victim of harassment/trolling so clearly i have some bias there.